# Why does the security of RSA depend on the non-factorability of the modulus n?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, modulus

Just wondering why does the security of RSA depend on the non-factorability of the modulus n?

Cheers!

Comment: This is a question about [crypto.se] and not a programming question. (I used the wrong close reason)

Comment: `n = p * q` By factoring `n` you get `p` and `q`. Hint: what else can be calculated from `p`, `q` and the public `e` value? [RSA (cryptosystem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well ... the non-factorability of the modulus n is not the whole story ...

as vlad already pointed out, you can easily calculate the private exponent if you know the factors of n ...

(p-1)(q-1) ... or more in general... if you know the prime factors P[i] of a number n, then you can calculate the product of all (P[i] - 1)... that is eulers PHI function ... to know the number of invertible multiplicative elements mod n

if you can factorize n, that calculation becomes trivial ... if n consists of only 2 large primes, and that factorization is hard, that isn't really trivial ...

however ... if you come up with another idea of calculating PHI(n) ... the number of elements mod n that have a multiplicative inverse ... factorization would probably no longer be your problem ...

currently there is no other public known way of calculating phi, than eulers way ... prod(P[i] - 1)

so either finding a way to factorize, or calculating PHI(n) a different way, would probably lead to breaking RSA

Answer (score 0):

The public data in RSA is n - the public modulus, and e - the public exponent. The secret is d - the private exponent. 
When creating the parameters you first generate two random primes p and q and then compute the public modulus n = p*q. So p and q are the factorization of n. Actually you could use more primes, but most use just two.
Then you choose the public exponent e, which is usually a small prime such as 65537 or 17 or even 3. 
Your secret exponent d would then be d = 1/e mod (p-1)(q-1).

So clearly anyone could compute d if they knew p and q, which is the factorization.